# Function of a Markov process and its generator

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-process

Suppose I have a Markov process $X_{t}$ with state space $\Omega$ and generator $L$.

I consider a function $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R$.

Is the couple $(X_t, f(X_t))$ still a Markov process?

If yes, is it possible to construct its generator?

Comment: No, there are conditions on $f$ (beyond measurability) for this to hold. It should be easy to construct a counterexample when $f$ is not injective.

Comment: @Math1000 : Perhaps you can explain your idea, or where you see a potential issue. This looks just like a relabeling of the states, regardless of f.

Comment: You can call states anything you want: If the states are $\{1,2,3\}$ you can equally call them $\{(1,f(1)),(2,f(2)),(3,f(3))\}$ or $\{a, b, c\}$. Changing the name of the states does not change the fundamental dynamics between those states.

Comment: Well I know in general that $f(X_t)$ is not a Markov process. I am not sure that extends to $(X_t,f(X_t))$, but I would be surprised if it didn't.

Comment: I see. But there should not be a surprise because $f(X_t)$ for noninjective  $f$ leaves ambiguity about the underlying state $X_t$ (Just consider $f=0$). But the tuple $(X_t,f(X_t))$ leaves no ambiguity regardless of whether or not $f$ is injective. It tells us the state $X_t$ in its first coordinate, and we do not need to look at the second coordinate $f(X_t)$ because we already know it: It is a deterministic function of the state $X_t$. So indeed $(X_t, f(X_t))$ is just a more complicated name for state $X_t$.